# SPI -- unstable clock confuses the SPI decoder

Tags: circuit-design, spi

I am sending bytes `0xAA` *(`10101010`)* and `0xBB` *(`10111011`)* over SPI and it works! Then I try to decode the signal using the open source tool Pulseview where SPI decoder is not the best and it latches data on every clock change.

This is where I get into trouble, because my SPI clock i.e. `iCE_SCK` is for some reason oscillating at the higher frequency before the transmission *(in the reset state)* and SPI decoder also decodes that!

[image]

It would be completely fine to somehow prevent `iCE_SCK` clock from oscillating in the reset state.

This is the schematics *(I marked `iCE_SCK` for convenience)*:

[image]

I tried putting the pullup/pulldown resistor of 10k to the `iCE_SCK` but it would not help the issue. Do you maybe have any other idea?

---

It looks I was lucky once when I used the `FLASH_MOSI` line to trigger on the falling edge:

[image]

Unfortunately this is not reproducible... Sometimes it works... Sometimes it does not. There are still some SPI decoding at the beginning where clock `iCE_SCK` is faster *(in reset state)*.

---

When I use external triggering on the `iCE_SS_BS` (`CS`) and then use two probes on the `FLASH_MOSI` and `iCE_SCK` it looks like this - SPI decoding starts too soon anad it fails.

[image]

Comment: Which of these chips is the SPI master? Is it just a problem with Pulseview or a more fundamental problem? Latching is also controlled by the SPI chip select. Have you tried to connect it to Pulseview as well?

Comment: @Codo FT232H is the master. My problem is also that my oscilloscope has only 2 probes. Therefore in Pulseview I cannot have signals MOSI, SCK and CS at once. Regarding this I filed an upstream request [here](https://sigrok.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1739). This is why I am searching for other solution that would make clock stable.

Comment: You could trigger a conversion on CS, then all pulses before are irrelevant.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I agree. But this is only possible with 3 oscilloscope probes. Please read the shorcommings of the SPI decoder in Pulseview [here](https://sigrok.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1739).

Comment: Another idea: Fix the firmware or get a different decoder(all opinions).

Comment: Have you tried the external trigger?

Comment: @Andyaka That also came to my mind, but even if it is fixed, the OP won't get the benefits of it, since it has only 2ch scope.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Hmmm using the external trigger could be the solution! Andyaka Fixing the firmware at this point could solve the problem in the future, but I need the solution now.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I tried triggering on the falling edge of the CS... At the end I got the same image than before and SPI decoder makes the same decoding "mistake". How exactly would you trigger in my case?

Comment: I suggest getting a dedicated, multi-channel logic analyzer, such as [this one](https://www.sigrok.org/wiki/Kingst_LA2016), supported by Pulseview.  The KingstVIS included is good too.  Confirm what the LA "sees" with the 'scope though; the LA input impedance is really tiny, so it likes to pickup noise and interpret as garbage.

Comment: @rdtsc I know... Probably for me at this point it is impossible to aviod an investment in a new gear... If anyone has any idea on how to avoid that I would be happy.

Comment: What is so bothering, at least you didn't loose the data yet at the beginning and the garbage filled only the remained space. The instrument is valuable if you can debug something. Still you have to use your brains, no instrument will give you the answer. Now what is so disturbing from your point of view?

Comment: "SPI decoder makes the same decoding mistake", I see now. Post the image of what you got usin the ext. trigger. Make also one acquisition with CS and SCK, so we can see this transition .

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Check the last image... SPI decoding starts before the trigger...

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a setting in the DSO for trigger. Mine has pre-trigger and post-trigger delay. Yours: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Users+Guide+DS1000E.pdf , if I do search pre post trigger:  Pre-trigger/delayed trigger: The data collected before and after trigger.
The trigger position is typically set at the horizontal center of the screen. In the
full-screen display the 6div data of pre-trigger and delayed trigger can be
surveyed. More data of pre-trigger and 1s delayed trigger can be surveyed by
adjusting the horizontal knob.

Comment: You have also Pulse Width Trigger, you can trigger acquisition when SCK pulse width becomes larger - clock frequency gets slower. No need for ext. trigger at all.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič If I use pulse width trigger. I get the same result. SPI decoder starts decoding too soon and is then confised. Probably the solution lies in the pre/post trigger settings which I can't mannage to understand on my Rigol DS1102E.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Finally! The solution was to move the trigger to the far left of the screen and then run the measurement. This is how I just got rid of the fast oscillating clock at the reset state! Now everything decodes fine as shown in the last image.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution *(in my case where I have only 2 oscilloscope probes)* was to move the trigger to the far left side of the screen and then run the measurement. This is how I manually removed the pretrigger data and SPI decoder does not get confused.

Here is the working example:
[image]